# Eevee CP 282 Evolve or potentiate?

Tags: pokemon-go

The question is simple. I caught an Eevee CP282 so I potentiate and maybe reach a 320-330 CP (I have just 2-3 extra candy) or evolve right now and potentially after?

Answer (score 2):

The order of evolving or feeding candy doesn't matter. There is no difference after you have done both.

Comment: This is true on the CP side. However you should probably feeding candy after evolving that way you won't feed a pokemon with bad moves.

Comment: Correct, but that wasn't the question. I usually don't feed candy at all, unless I need a fighter for the gym.